# Prove that every connected graph with at least 3 vertices that contains a cycle has at least |V | edges.

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

I'm new to proofs and I'm trying to prove the one in the title for an undirected graph. However, I'm very restricted to the methods I can use. I was given the definition of a $cycle$, a $path$ and a $connected$ $component$ and I may or may not use these facts without further proof:

- If a node $v$ has a path to another node $u$, then $\deg(v) > 0$ and $\deg(u) > 0$.
- $\sum_{v \in V} \deg(v) = 2|E|$

This means I cannot use other terms like e.g., "tree" or facts about trees.
I've spent a few days now on this problem. I tried to reformulate ideas from similar proofs like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870817/let-h-be-a-simple-graph-on-n-vertices-that-has-m-edges-prove-that-h-con) or use strategies like the one in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voD1xLxZvAM). All my previous solutions have not been convincing so far or I got stuck somewhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use induction? What if there was a vertex with degree $1$ and you removed it leaving a graph with one less vertex and one less edge?

Comment: I've tried that approach. this would eventually leave me only with vertices of degree $> 1$. As a next step I can use the technique from the youtube video to prove that the graph contains a circle but I cannot come to the conclusion that a graph with a circle has at least $|V|$ edges.

Comment: Good! And now use the second fact.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show that a cycle of $k$ vertices has $k$ edges?

If so, start by supposing there is a cycle of $k$ vertices and observe that the remaining $n - k$ vertices each need to be connected to the cycle. How many edges does that imply?

Comment: I really like that approach. After showing a cycle with $k$ vertices has $k$ edges this would eventually lead me to strong induction, as I understand it (we only learned the standard induction method in class but that should be ok).
Now from the definition of a path ("A path is a sequence $(u1, u2), (u2, u3),..., (uk−1, uk)$ of edges of $E$ such that $k > 0$ and $u_i \in V$  for all $1 \leq i \leq k$") and a circle ("A cycle is a path of at least 3 edges, i.e., $k \geq 4$, such that $u_1 = u_k$") couldn't I conclude that a circle must have equal vertices and edges from the definition alone?