# If a graph $G$ has $n$ vertice and $m$ edges ($m \ge n$), Then G has at least $m-n+1$ cycles

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

This conclusion is true when G is a simple graph.

By the proof:[Let $H$ be a simple graph on $n$ vertices that has $m$ edges. Prove that $H$ contains at least $m-n+1$ cycles.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870817/let-h-be-a-simple-graph-on-n-vertices-that-has-m-edges-prove-that-h-con)

However, is it true for every graph (not just a simple graph) ?

As G has extra loops and multilpe edges, I find the proof above can't be promoted to all the graph easily. So is the conclusion true?

I have also tried to construst a converse example using loops and multiple edges but I fail to contrust a graph whose cycles no more than $m-n$

Comment: Every graph $G$ has an underlying simple graph $H$ from which it can be constructed by adding  repeated edges and loops. Think of the effect on $m$ and on $m-n+1$ of adding these new edges and loops (there is no effect on $n$).

Comment: The proof is exactly the same whether or not loops and parallel edges are allowed (assuming that a loop and a pair of parallel edges are both considered to be cycles).